# looking for a 1 line remote backup command that excludes directories and writes to file

Tags: linux, backup

scp doesn't exclude directories and rsync doesn't write/pipe to an image file or .tar (that I can find)

I have remote servers I would like to burn quick backups for. I just need to exclude the /run/, /sys/ and /dev/ folders so the live device doesn't crash when backing up.

I'm also trying to avoid creating a loop device if possible.

Writing to a raw image file is ideal.

What's a good 1 line script that will write remote backup data to an image file while excluding directories?

Comment: Curious: why does a moderately complex backup mechanism need to exist in a single line

Comment: I figured after 20 years somebody would have come up with something straight forward. This has got to be close to the #1 job on an admin's box. I've gone looking for this for years and always came up empty handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tar on the remote machine and have it write to standard output, and bring the data back to the local machine by redirecting ssh's output to a local file. You will no doubt have to fine-tune the tar options shown below but it should do what you want:

```
ssh "root@$REMOTEHOST" tar --exclude /run --exclude /dev --exclude /sys --exclude /proc cvf - / > /backups/REMOTEHOST.$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
```

Be sure to test the image file with "tar tvf" or the like. Sorry, that'll make it at least two lines, but if you're not testing your backups then you're not really backing up.

Comment: It took a little cleaning up.  ssh "root@192.168.42.13" tar --exclude='./run' --exclude='./dev' --exclude='./sys' --exclude='./proc' -cvf - / > '192.168.42.13'.$(date +%Y%m%d).tar